# Streaming .m3u8 Content to Google Cast-Compatible TVs Using ExoPlayer an Jetpack Compose – Need Assistance with Integration

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, exoplayer, google-cast-sdk

let me explain my issue. I'm developing an app that needs to stream a .m3u8 file via URL to TV devices compatible with Google Cast. So far, I've managed to implement a video player using ExoPlayer that can display the real-time stream.

Now, I would like to view the same content on a TV. I've had difficulty finding documentation, which is why I'm reaching out for your assistance. If anyone has experience in this area and would be kind enough to help me with this issue, I would greatly appreciate it. Greetings and happy coding!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.